# visual studio extension (VSPackage) add items to Test Explorer context menu

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, vspackage

I am writing an extension to Visual studio 2012 using VSPackage. I need to add a context menu entry to Test Explorer and on click of this menu item, I need to get the selected unit test(s). I tried to add an item using

```
((CommandBars)DTE.CommandBars)["Test Window Context Menu"].Controls.Add(Type: MsoControlType.msoControlButton);
```

and adding an event handler by subscribing to the event

```
DTE.Events.CommandBarEvents[command].Click
```

I succeeded in adding an item to Context menu but the Click event handler never gets fired. MSDN said, I needed to set the OnAction property of the command to a valid string value for the Click event handler to get fired. It didn't work either.

Then, I figured out I needed to add a command through the VSCT file in a VSPackage. However, I am not able to find the Test Window Context menu so that I can attach the command to it. Also, I need to get all the unit tests (TestCase objects) listed in the Test Explorer.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Usually these are the files I look for Visual Studio shell GUIDs or command, context menu, group, etc IDs:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Inc\stdidcmd.h
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Inc\vsshlids.h

Actually they are included in the top of your newly created .vsct file (<Extern href="vsshlids.h" />). I guess you've already checked them. I did a quick search, but what I found for "Test" is just a test ribbon and a test dialog. Probably now that you're looking for. It might be still useful for someone finding this post.

You might also want try it brute force style:
Search your Program Files (x86)\Visual Studio [VERSION] for regexp: ^#define.*TEST.*$
This shall give you the defines containing *TEST*.

Also you might want to consider asking Microsoft directly.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some exploratory code to loop over commands in that context menu. I also played around with registering a priority command target and seeing what group GUID and command ID I got. The GUID for that context menu appears to be `{1e198c22-5980-4e7e-92f3-f73168d1fb63}`. You can probably use that to add a command via the .vsct file without using the DTE.CommandBars to add it dynamically.

Here's my experiment code which lists the GUID and command ID of the commands currently in that context menu, in case it helps anyone.

```
var bars = ((Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBars)DTE.CommandBars);
var teContextMenu = bars["Test Window Context Menu"];
var ctls = teContextMenu.Controls;
foreach (var ctl in ctls)
{
    var cmdCtl = ctl as Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBarControl;
    string guid; int id;
    DTE.Commands.CommandInfo(ctl, out guid, out id);
    Debug.WriteLine($"{cmdCtl?.accName} {guid} {id}");
}
```

This article on command routing was helpful to me:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/command-routing-algorithm

My experimental priority command target, where I set a breakpoint to see what GUID and command IDs were sent, is registered as follows. The TestCommandInterceptor class is a bare-bones implementation of IOleCommandTarget.

```
var cmdService = GetService(typeof(SVsRegisterPriorityCommandTarget)) as IVsRegisterPriorityCommandTarget;
var target = new TestCommandInterceptor();
cmdService.RegisterPriorityCommandTarget(0, target, out _testCmdInterceptorRegistrationCookie);
```

I would still like to know the answer to the second part of this question about how to determine the selected tests.

Comment: This MSDN post seems to suggest that the second half of this, determining the selected tests, is not possible: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/54b60a75-3326-4e94-a506-82eba72db07c/how-to-get-the-selected-item-on-the-visual-studio-environment-test-windows?forum=vsx